# How can i make ruby on rails handle duplicate record errors from MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, insert, unique-constraint

I have a unique index on multiple fields on my database. So if you try to call save on a duplicate record, it raises ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid and shows the mysql error. Is there a way to handle this within rails either by creating the unique constraint, or otherwise have it return a relevant error message when this happens?

heres the trace:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '2010-12-09-2-0-1-1' for key 2: INSERT INTO `entries` (`rejected_at`, `created_at`, `comments`, `overtime`, `submitted_at`, `updated_at`, `time`, `approved`, `day`, `user_id`, `approved_at`, `job_id`, `submitted`, `rejected`) VALUES(NULL, '2010-12-09 21:50:46', NULL, 0, NULL, '2010-12-09 21:50:46', 2.0, NULL, '2010-12-09', 1, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL)
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `log'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:319:in `execute'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:259:in `insert_sql'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:329:in `insert_sql'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:44:in `insert_without_query_dirty'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:18:in `insert'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2901:in `create_without_timestamps'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:53:in `create_without_callbacks'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:266:in `create'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2867:in `create_or_update_without_callbacks'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:250:in `create_or_update'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2538:in `save_without_validation'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1078:in `save_without_dirty'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_without_transactions'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 from /home/cmatthews/src/cannon/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a uniqueness constraint to your model so that the record returns with errors and is invalid.

For example (Rails 2):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => [:name, :age]
end
```

or (Rails 3)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:name, :age]}
end
```

This should result in the following:

```
user1 = User.create :email => "one@example.com", :name => "one", :age => 20
user2 = User.create :email => "one@example.com", :name => "one", :age => 20
user2.valid? # false
```

Comment: i know i can do that for one field but can i do it for multiple ones as in can i have it check to see if they have the same: email, name,favorite color, and job. There can be 5 people named john, but only one can have JOhn@example.com, orange, and be a programmer. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey, I updated the post with the answer for multiple attributes.

Comment: Whilst that covers most of the use cases, there is and always has been a race condition in validates_uniqueness_of - it doesnt stop duplicate entries completely due to the way it works.

Comment: That's correct Omar.  You should still have a unique index in MySQL on (name, age, email) and it's best to surround your updates with begin..rescue..end statements to catch these cases if you suspect this might be an issue for your application.

Answer (score 18):

```
begin
  Event.create!(:name => 'Ironman Lanzarote 2011')
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
  # handle duplicate entry 
end
```

This works for me under Rails 3.

Comment: This violates the principle of least astonishment and does not follow conventions in Rails.

Comment: When you use a master/slave-setup, you will run into drifting problems (and the resulting race conditions), which can easily be resolved using this approach, instead of using rails' unique validation, which might check it on the slave.

Comment: This is fine, but I would put this behaviour on a model method with a descriptive name.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the query to

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `entries` ...
```

Alternatively, you could consider `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`.

The `INSERT` Documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Comment: i think that would somewhat solve the problem, but the SQL query is auto generated. I could alter it, except i want it to raise an error, just one that I can catch and have a message, this just makes the server say 500 internal server error.